# WebApi core 2.2 JWT Token not been Authorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was able to generate the token but if I tried to Authorize in my controller it doesn't work.

I create a class JWT but I didn't set the issuer or audience.

```
private List<Claim> Claim = new List<Claim>();
    public string GetUserToken(string tp,string id)
    {
        var sck = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")));
        var sc = new SigningCredentials(sck, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        if(tp == "Host")
        {
            Claim.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Host"));
            Claim.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, id));
        }
        else
        {
            Claim.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Client"));
            Claim.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, id));
        }

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(               
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            signingCredentials: sc,
            claims: Claim
            );
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

and Inside of `Startup` class :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var SymmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")));
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
            AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,                    
                IssuerSigningKey = SymmetricSecurityKey
            };
        });
```

And in my controller I just put `[Authorize(Roles ="Host")]`. Even removing the `Roles` attribute still the same result, `401 Unauthorized`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your key and jwt configuration, your startup class should looks something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            //Get the key from configuration file section
            var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

            //jwt configuration 
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x => {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //Configuration of cors to allow request of anothers 
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            //Use the authentication service
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: It does have the information. in the configure method, I only have the `app.UseAuthentication();`. I'll add the others and test

Comment: same thing, Unauthorized!

Comment: please share your startup file

Comment: @NathielPaulino are you're sure you're using the DefaultChallenge and Authentication Scheme

Comment: @Zachdev you have AddAuthentication Twice,  that will probably mess something up

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake with a piace of code from the @NathielPaulino code